# Not able to add System.Net.Http to Project updated to 4.6.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, .net-4.6.1

I just updated my MVC Project from .Net 4.6 to .Net 4.6.1.
But when I start the Application, there is an error, that System.Net.Http is missing.

[image]

In the add reference dialog I can see the reference:

[image]

But in the list, there is an icon, that is indicating a warning:

[image]

I tried to remove and add the reference again several times with no luck.
I also tried it with a new MVC Project based on .Net 4.6.1 and here it works like a charm.

So what can I do, to get a reference to System.Net.Http in my existing Project?

Comment: What happens if you run `Update-Package -Reinstall -IgnoreDependencies` from the `Package Manager Console`?

Comment: It is still the same

Answer (score 0):

First go to your csproj  file, check if the version is the same with your packages.config ? 
if yes also check in your bin folder is it the same version, all of them should be the same version, if not remove that line, and also go to your packages.config and search for the library and remove that line again. then add the library again.
first image is for csproj file line 
[image: csproj file]

here bin folder 
[image: bin folder]

and here packeges.config 
[image: Packages]

as I mentioned check all 3 have the same version, and no duplicate, if not remove all and add again and check for the dll in the bin folder is it generated or not. 
I hope this help.

Comment: Since .Net 4.6.1 System.Net.Http is part of the framework, it is not necessary to add it via nuget. When you create a new MVC Project just from the scratch in 4.6.1 System.Net.Http is included as an normal Framework reference.